# Executing procedure from web create less records than running from SQL Management Studio

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

On MS SQL I have procedure CM_Export that insert records to table. When I run it directly from SQL Management Studio ( `EXEC dbo.CM_Export 'DB1', 'DB2', 1` ), it inserts 80 rows. But when I run it from web, it inserts only 20 rows. In both cases it takes 1 second. In web I try 2 ways:

1)

```
    $sql = "EXEC dbo.CM_Export 'DB1', 'DB2', 1";
sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

2)

```
  $tsql = "{call CM_Export(?, ?, ?)}";

$params = array(array("DB1", SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
 array("DB2", SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
 array(1, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
);

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $tsql, $params);    
if($stmt) {    
 echo "Statement prepared.\n";    
} else {    
 echo "Error in preparing statement.\n";    
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));    
}    

if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {    
 echo "Statement executed.\n";
} else {
 echo "Error in executing statement.\n";
 die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
```

No error occured. I try catch in profiler what runs and when I copy it to Management Studio, so procedure inserts 80 rows and from web 20. When I add to stored procedure TRANS, so running from web is no rows added. But there aren't error - running from Management Studio is again OK. I also try tracelog and there is:

EXIT  SQLExecDirectW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)

When I make multiple refresh (Ctrl + R without TRANS in procedure), so from first 20 rows procedure add another rows and I'm able to create about 40 rows. So it seems that problem is in some timeout. But add timeout parametr to script haven't no effect.

```
sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array('QueryTimeout' => 100))
```

In trace log I also find:

WCHAR *             0x50418B34  [-3]

Google says that this is samo problem with ODBC driver that use SQL. I use SQL 2008 R2 64b.

Comment: Do you use the same database-user to run the statement?

Answer (score 1):

So I have found solution - [add SET NOCOUNT ON to stored procedure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldriverforphp/thread/e0908b2f-4afa-4626-830d-9683486186c8) !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the sqlsrv_free_stmt?   It might be that the statement is being freed before the work is done.

The statement should still be cleaned up when the script is finished executing.

Comment: Yes, I try it. I also try add waiting cyclce    for($i = 1; $i <= 999999; $i++) {echo($i);}   and no effect.